# How to replace the zero value of field in xlsx report. Odoo 14

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I work with 'excel_import_export' OCA module, I want to add condition for 'E5' by replacing Zeros by blank :

```
  <field name="input_instruction"> 
    { '__EXPORT__': 
    { 1: { '_HEAD_': 
    { 'B2': 'partner_id.display_name${value or ""}#{align=left;style=text}', }, '_EXTEND_results': 
    { 'A5': 'name${value or ""}#{style=text}',
     'B5': 'date_order${value or ""}#{style=date}', 
     'C5': 'amount_untaxed${value or 0}#{style=number}@{sum}',
     'D5': 'amount_tax${value or 0}#{style=number}@{sum}',
     'E5': 'amount_total${value or 0}#{style=number}', }, }, }, }
 </field>
```

I try with this code , but I still having error:

```
'E5': 'amount_total${value or 0}#{style=number}' if amount_total!=0.0 else ' '
```

How can I do it? Any help please?
Thanks